# How to Load files with the same name in data flow Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I use data flow in Azure data factory And I set as source dataset files with the same name. The files have named “name_date1.csv” end “name_date2.csv”. I set path “name_*.csv”. I want that data flow load in sink db only data of  “name_date1”. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and able to get the desired file to sink using `Column to store file name` option in source options.

These are my source files in storage.

[image]

I have given name_*.csv in wild card of source as same as you to read multiple files.

[image]

In source options, go to `Column to store file name` and give a name and this will store the file name of every row in new column.

[image]

[image]

Then use **filter transformation** to get the row only from a particular file.

`notEquals(instr(filename,'name_date1'),0)`

[image]

After this give your sink and you can get the rows from your desired file only.

Comment: Is there a method where I can load only data from “name_date1”without specific “name_date1” file?

Comment: can I use foreach and lookup with data flow?

Comment: Use Get Meta activity to get all file names(`Childitems`) from that folder and give that array to a ForEach activity and inside that use the dataflow activity and pass the `@item().name` as a parameter to dataflow. In dataflow filter expression you can use that parameter as per your filter condition.

Comment: Can you show me that please?

Comment: 'Is there a method where I can load only data from “name_date1” without specific “name_date1” file?' can you be clearer on this? how you are going to get the data from that file if you don't want to specify that name in filter transformation?